# how to use height: -webkit-fill-available

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

I want to fill the remaining portion left in nested Div with background color & after many R&D I got to know that it can be done by using height: -webkit-fill-available. Can anyone tell me how to use this webkit-fill-available feature in Visual studio 2015

Comment: Where's your markup?

Comment: Show your [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>webkit fix</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
      display: grid;
      align-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>webkit fix</h1>
</body>
```

As you move the browser around you should see it stays in the middle. Oddly enough [it doesn't seem properly documented on MDN - search result appear but  there's nothing on the actual pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=webkit-fill-available)